# Keeping track of an ArrayList in a different class [Java]

Tags: java, arraylist

Making a swing app for my self, my GUI needs to get some data from my DataBase class. The data will exist in the form of ArrayList < MyClass > where MyClass is a class I've written. The problem I'm facing is that, I can't send the ArrayList to the GUI in its entirety because then I would have to import MyClass into my GUI package (DataBase and GUI are in different packages). I just need some fields from MyClass so I should send those as String[] instead.

The GUI will need only need one String[] from only one MyClass object at a time. Also the ArrayList cannot advance until I manually tell it to, since I will need to change some fields in MyClass depending on what the user does in the GUI. During this time, other methods from DataBase may be called so this should not cause me to lost my place in the ArrayList.

My Solution: Create a method which gets the current MyClass object, puts the needed fields in a String[] and returns that String[]. To keep track of my place in the ArrayList, I use a private field in DataBase which is only updated after all the changes have been made to the current MyClass object.

Is there a simpler way of doing this? My solution seems rather convoluted, especially since I may require multiple methods to make the necessary changes to the current MyClass object.

Not sure if this is enough information so let me know if you need more. I don't think posting my code here is a good idea because both DataBase and GUI are very big classes each using several other big classes.

Comment: I don't want about swing, but what do you mean by importing MyClass into your GUI package ?  I think you can use Dozer, to create a POJO that suits your purpose and avoid using the array.

Comment: @de_xtr I have two packages, one with my logic and another with my view (MVC design). DataBase and MyClass are in logic, and GUI is in view. I don't want to create a coupling between the two packages so that's why I don't to import MyClass into GUI.

Comment: So what you need is a DTO, or a data transfer object. You can create a DTO and keep the required fields there and then use Dozer to populate those fields.

Comment: @de_xtr Didn't know what DTO was so I looked it up, isn't that more work than my solution? Also my app will run locally on my machine so I wont be making any expensive server calls.

Comment: DTO is a pattern that will make your solution more generic and easier to maintain/modify. You will face difficulty, if you need to need to transfer some other data tomorrow. If you have a DTO, voila! It's as easy as adding one more field! 
http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html